# Facebook Graph API Search returning empty data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-applications

Facebook search API returning empty data set since last couple of days. This worked fine for me till 2-3 days back.

The repro is consistent, even with the sample on Graph API developers page: 
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=watermelon&type=post

{
   "data": [

]
}

Any idea what's going on?

Thanks!

Comment: We are having the same issue, you are not alone :/

Comment: I clicked on the link you poster, but the data is not empty

Comment: It is a known bug. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/385073941575300

Answer (score 0):

This looks like working now. Might be a temp issue.